# Concat Values In MySQL Query(To Handle Null Values)

Tags: mysql

I am writing a PHP and MySQL application in which i have to concatenate multiple column values into one  single column.I would have used the concat() function,but it does not handle null values,and  the concat_ws(),which does not return the result in the output i want.
 What i need can be achieved in the Oracle database like this:

```
 Select 'The Surname Is'||last_name from employees;
```

My Issue is how can i achieve this same result with MySQL..without using the above named functions?

Answer (score 28, accepted):

[CONCAT](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/string-functions.html#function_concat) with [IFNULL](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/control-flow-functions.html#function_ifnull):

```
SELECT
  CONCAT('The Surname Is ', IFNULL(last_name, 'sadly not available'))
FROM `employees`
```

Answer (score 10):

@Minesh: CONCAT_WS does not 'take care' of NULL values. To illustrate this...

```
CONCAT_WS("~",house.name,house.address,house.type)
```

In the above example, if *house.address* is *NULL* the returned result will not contain a neat double tilda (~~) as expected. It will be a tilda separated list with only 1 tilda. eg "fun House~mansion"

Comment: it does remove it along with it's separator, where is the problem in that? it's the neat solution unless you wanted to do something else

Comment: I consider it bad because the function performs 2 different tasks, the second of which is not suggested by the function name. First it concatenates, great, thanks, that's what I wanted. Then it removes blank string list items, woah, I didn't ask you to do that. The function should be called CONCAT_NN_WS() where the NN stands for "Not Nulls". If I ask my software to just concatenate 5 things into a list, I expect a 5 item list. I don't then expect the software to then say "Oh by the way, I emptied the bins, fed the cat and phoned your mum to invite her for the weekend too"

Comment: You're right this will be useful and it should have been implemented (keeping this method as well for other purposes).

Answer (score 9):

You can also use CONCAT_WS function which takes care of NULL values

```
SELECT 
CONCAT_WS(' ','The Surname Is',lastname) 
FROM `employees`
```

Answer (score 4):

Use [coalesce](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/comparison-operators.html#function_coalesce) to concat an empty string

```
select concat(coalesce(null, ''));
```

Answer (score 1):

A little trick: Use empty string like separator with CONCAT_WS (Some times you wan't insert white spaces)

```
CONCAT_WS('','The Surname Is:',lastname) 
FROM `employees`
```